# Saving UITextField Objects into NSArray

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsarray

I have an input form which is to be created dynamically using an NSArray to fill the description fields on the left side (UILabels).
On the right side there should be a corresponding UITextField for each UILabel.

I would like (I actually have) to dynamically create those UITextFields, save them into an NSArray and then be able to access their possibly modified text values, when the "Done" button is pressed to evaluate the form.

Apparently, just adding them to the NSArray will only store a copy of the object in its recent representation. How can I store a real "link"? 
I am using ARC.

Comment: What's about the thing if use text field's delegate functions to fulfill your requirement?

Comment: NSArray copying the objects, so as the user edits text field you should update the array manually. It would be better if you use NSMutableDictionary with textFields as key and text as its value. Then you can populate the array accordingly.

Comment: NSDictionary is only good for objects staying unique. Modifying a UITextField text would alter the whole object and insert it AGAIN into the NSDictionary not replacing the old occurrence. Or am I missing something?

Comment: NSArray is not mutable I guess you were pointing to using NSMutableArray and altering the object.

Comment: Yes. I thought this would be clear enough to assume, so I only mentioned the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It already happens. What is stored in the NSArray appears to be a link, not a copy after all. I just had another bug hiding the real results.